# Ruby on Rails Gem & Plugin Overload! Where/how to keep up-to-date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm enjoying Ruby on Rails but one thing that seems overwhelming is the shear number of **gems** and **plugins** and their **branches** that exist out in the wild. Sure I could `gem list --remote` but that doesn't tell me squat other than confirming that there are hundreds (*thousands?*) of gems. How are people keeping track of what's hot and what's been left behind? In just about every category there is the old/neglected/out-of-date, a current "standard" or community "poster-child", and one or two up-and-comers.

For example in the Authentication category so far I've found (not to mention the many branches):

- acts_as_authenticated
- restful_authentication
- authlogic
- devise

It seems as though the first two may be on their way out (apologies if I'm wrong). **Authlogic** appears to be the *current* "standard" and **devise** is the up-and-comer? well, i'm making huge assumptions that are surely wrong but that's why I'm looking for answers *(not to this authentication example but to the general question)*.

What/where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) is a great place to go if you have something specific in mind.

I like [Ruby5](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/) for keeping up to date on the latest stuff.

Comment: I've been enjoying (read: catching up on) Ruby5! Ruby Toolbox looks great! thanks!